# Unable to clear margin left and right in css

Tags: html, css

Here is my [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d30r6g6h/):

It has some space in margin left and right side. I need to set full width for footer and header.

I set table `width: 100%;` but it didn't change.

So i set `width: 960px;`, now it shows some space in margin left and right.

css:

```
#templatePreheader{
    /*@editable*/background-color:#ffffff;
    /*@editable*/border-top:0;
    /*@editable*/border-bottom:0;
    /*@editable*/width:960px;
}

#templateFooter{
    /*@editable*/background-color:#FFFFFF;
    /*@editable*/border-top:0;
    /*@editable*/border-bottom:0;
    /*@editable*/width:960px;
}
```

May i know , how to do this.

Note: It is the email template. so need to change only in css.

Can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: You should always set a unit (like "px", for example): *border-top:0px*

Comment: @Robert It is not needed for `0`!

Comment: @Robert No, for 0 it is even considered bad practice if you set a unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you need to make sure your width assignments on a table and/or its cells are respected, apply

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

to your tables' CSS.

In your specific case, this won't solve the issue.

Your problem is that you `#templateFooter` sits inside a `table#templateContainer` which is assigned `width="600"` attribute in your markup.

Comment: If you have to keep the current HTML structure and `table#templateContainer` `width`: No.

Comment: Sorry.. i cant understand.. finally i have to set full width for header and footer...can you please help me..

Comment: You wrote: "so need to change only in css.". This is not possible without changing the surrounding table width as well.

Comment: Because this is email template ya.. and it is responsive too..so only i said like that..

Answer (score 1):

The `td#bodyCell` has 10px padding.

```css
#bodyCell {padding: 0;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/b1zksqyy/

Comment: actually. ..i already tried #bodycel:0;.. but it shows only jsfiddle. if i run localhost.. it doesn't happens..

Comment: It worked for me even after I stored the files on my machine.

Comment: No. it is working @PralhadNarsinhSonar: here is screenshot.. http://s12.postimg.org/bh5b17p71/untitled.jpg .. it only working in top and bottom ..

Comment: @saina Can you put that page online somewhere?

Comment: may i know.. how to use?

Comment: Try... If you don't succeed, ask!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80364/discussion-between-saina-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

I just tried something with the header and it seems to work. Give this a try.

```
    #templatePreheader{
        /*@editable*/background-color:#ffffff;
        /*@editable*/border-top:0;
        /*@editable*/border-bottom:0;
        /*@editable*/width:100%;
          position:absolute;
          top:0;
          left:0;

    }
```

Comment: Positioning in emails are bad!